# Integration help. How does $\cos(2ωτ-ωt)$ become $\sin(ωτ)/ω$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I came across this integration as I was studying convolution problems and I am stumped by how $\cos(2ωτ−ωt)$ became $\frac{\sin(ωτ)}{ω}$. I'm sorry, but can anyone help me with this?

$$\begin{split}
h(t)&=\frac{\sin(ωt)}{ω}* \frac{\sin(ωt)}{ω}\\
&=\frac{1}{ω^2}\int^t_0[\sin(ωτ)\sin(ω(t-τ))]dτ\\
&=\frac{1}{2ω^2}\int^t_0[-\cos(ωt)+\cos(2ωτ-ωt)]dτ\\
&=\frac{1}{2ω^2}\left[-τ\cos(ωt)+\frac{\sin(ωτ)}{ω}\right]_0^t
\end{split}$$

Thank you so much for helping me.

Extra info (which I don't know is relevant or not):
H(s) is Laplace transformed. The textbook says,
"Let

$$\begin{split}
H(s)=\frac{1}{(s^2+ω^2)^2} 
\end{split}$$
Find h(t)." It goes on to say,

"The inverse of 1/((s^2+ω^2)^2) is sin(ωt)/ω...

Comment: Can you provide some more context regarding the original question?

Comment: It's a Convolution problem. 
H(s) is Laplace transformed. The textbook question goes:
"Let H(s)=1/((s^2+ω^2)^2). Find h(t)."
It goes on to say, 
"The inverse of 1/((s^2+ω^2)^2) is sin(ωt)/ω..."

Comment: I've edited your question to improve formatting. There were some ambiguities that I almost missed. Please do check that I didn't mess up any of your formulas in my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Nothing seems to be wrong.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake with the first line. Previously it read sin(ωτ)/ω. I fixed it to sin(ωt)/ω. But it shouldn't have fundamentally affected the clarity of my question since posting...

Comment: It might be worth editing the question to include this context @DPPark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note
$$
\cos(2\omega\tau - \omega t) = \cos\big((2\tau-t)\omega\big)
$$
Change variables, $s=2\tau - t$ and $ds = 2\;d\tau$
$$
\int_0^t\cos(2\omega\tau - \omega t)\;d\tau
=\int_0^t \cos\big((2\tau-t)\omega\big)\;d\tau
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-t}^t \cos(s\omega)\;ds
=\int_0^t \cos(s\omega)\;ds = \left[\frac{\sin(s\omega)}{\omega}\right]_{s=0}^t
$$

Comment: Perfect answer, but we all agree that applying a substitution and the evenness property to just one half of the integral of a sum, all in one step, like the text apparently did, is totally bogus and the OP needn't feel bad for not seeing it, right?

Comment: My book says the lower bound of integral when evaluating is τ=0.  Your answer gives me s=0 as the lower bound, but it doesnt change the solution to the question. My textbook is a very "comprehensive" book and likes taking shortcuts. Maybe my textbook is at fault concerning the lower bound. Thank you for this great answer!